# Chrome manifest Google URL

Tags: google-chrome, manifest

I have been trying to look for a better alternative, but I can't seem to find a better way to do this.

My current Chrome Extension manifest has about 300 lines of code that includes these kinds of URL's.

```
   "http://www.google.com/webhp*", "https://www.google.com/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.ad/webhp*", "https://www.google.ad/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.ae/webhp*", "https://www.google.ae/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.com.af/webhp*", "https://www.google.com.af/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.com.ag/webhp*", "https://www.google.com.ag/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.com.ai/webhp*", "https://www.google.com.ai/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.am/webhp*", "https://www.google.am/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.co.ao/webhp*", "https://www.google.co.ao/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.com.ar/webhp*", "https://www.google.com.ar/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.as/webhp*", "https://www.google.as/webhp*",
    "http://www.google.at/webhp*", "https://www.google.at/webhp*",
```

I need to match URL's that run my script for https://www.google.com/ (exact), https://www.google.com/webph* (alternative for Google homepage) and https://www.google.com/search* (to match the search tabs that I want: images, videos, shopping, etc.)

The main problem lies with the fact that I can't use a wildcard for the domain extension (.com/.de/.org).

There has to be a better way right? My current manifest looks like a disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will always need to have your URL specifications somewhere, there is however an option to have it match in a broader way by moving it to JavaScript, and this gives you the option to move it away from the manifest if you desire.

In your manifest, simply declare the extension to inject the background script on all URLs:

```
"content_scripts": [{
   "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}]
```

And then in your background script, define where the extension should work, example:

```
var match = 'www.google.';
var excludes = ['maps', 'whatever'];    

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, info, tab) {
    if (tab.status !== "complete"){
        return;
    } 
    if(tab.url.indexOf(match) !== -1 && excludes.indexOf(tab.url) === -1){
        // inject your script
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {"file": "myScript.js"});
    }
}
```